# Problem executing postgres queries from a batch file

Tags: postgresql, batch-file

I'm having a problem while executing a batch file.
My batch file exits after he reach the line to execute postgres query

```
(
echo INSERT INTO Role SET roleName=%role%; INSERT INTO User (login, password, active, role) VALUE (%login%, %password%, 1, LAST_INSERT_ID());
) | psql -h %DB_HOST% -p 5432 -U %DB_USER% -d %DB_NAME%
```

can anyone help to solve this problem ?

```
@echo off
title Create New User
set DB_HOST=localhost
set DB_USER=postgres
set DB_NAME=appdb
@echo Enter a new Login:
set /p login=
ECHO ============================
@echo Enter a new password:
set /p password=
ECHO ============================
@echo Enter again your new password:
set /p passwordConfirm=
goto VerifyPassword
:VerifyPassword
if %password% == %passwordConfirm% goto insertInDatabase
if not %password% == %passwordConfirm% goto PasswordSection
:PasswordSection
@echo Password incorrect, please retype your password
@echo Enter a new password:
set /p password=
ECHO ============================
@echo Enter again your new password:
set /p passwordConfirm=
goto VerifyPassword
:insertInDatabase
ECHO ============================
@echo Choose role of the user Admin A\U User:
set /p role=
@echo Inserting in Database ...
(
echo INSERT INTO Role SET roleName=%role%; INSERT INTO User (login, 
password, active, role) VALUE (%login%, %password%, 1, LAST_INSERT_ID());
) | psql -h %DB_HOST% -p 5432 -U %DB_USER% -d %DB_NAME%
pause
exit
```

Comment: Well, this does not appear to be a [mcve]!

Answer (score 0):

I think, there are two problems:
1. Parentheses must be escaped
2. You query have syntax errors.

Try this:

```
(
    echo INSERT INTO role ^(Name^) select '%role%' where not exists ^(select 1 from role where lower^(name^) = lower^('%role%'^)^);
    echo INSERT INTO User ^(login, password, active, role^) select '%login%', '%password%', true, r.id from role r where lower^(name^) = lower^('%role%'^);
) | psql -h %DB_HOST% -p 5432 -U %DB_USER% -d %DB_NAME%
```